# How does inheritance work in this snippet of code?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am learning about inheritance and I am a bit confused by one of the problems I got. In this problem, why is the output `The color is orange` and not `The color is orangeThecolor is red`?

```
using namespace std;

class Red{
    public: void print(){
        cout<<"The color is red";
    }
};

class Orange: public Red{
    public: void print(){
        cout<<"The color is orange";
    }
};

class Yellow: public Orange{};

int main()
{
    Orange colorOrange;
    colorOrange.print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inheritance doesn't mean that all functions of the base classes are invoked automatically, if the derived classes functions are called. You must have misunderstood something.

Comment: So if I called an instance of the Yellow class and I tried the print function, would it not print anything at all? Or would it still print "The color is orange"

Comment: Each of the functions overrides the ancestor.  So if you want it to call the ancestor you must do so. For example, in the orange print function , add a Red::print() call at the bottom to call the base class.

Comment: As for your question in your last comment - just try it!

Comment: @ahahahahana The `print` function in the derived class **hides** the version from the base class. Refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of dupes for this. The books listed above are also available as PDFs.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle only virtual functions can be overriden.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.virtual I get you. But I wasn’t far off in saying to call base. Much like the answer.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Polymorphism Isn’t it? Use base class pointer which calls the derived class overridden virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the output "The color is orange" and not "The color is orangeThecolor is red"?

Because when you wrote `colorOrange.print();` lookup starts from the derived class and then it finds the `Yellow::print()` and so the search stops and this already found `print` is called/used. Thus you get the output `The color is orange` and nothing more.

In other words, the `print` inside the derived class **hides** the version from the base class.

If you want to call the `Red::print()` in addition to the `Yellow::print()` then you could add a call to base' print version by adding `Red::print()` as shown below:

```
class Orange: public Red{
    public: void print(){
        cout<<"The color is orange";
        //added this to call Red::print() 
        Red::print();
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/v_F4Ay9kT)